# Ubuntu 16.04 media codes missing

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc, media

I recently did a fresh install when going from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.  The old distro had been upgraded ~5 times from various older releases and I decided to start fresh.  I kept the user profile but reinstalled the OS.  During installation I selected to install restricted extras (or whatever it's called during setup).  Whenever I go to play practically any video type I get the "searching for plugins" prompt followed by "required plugin could not be found".  This is for fairly standard video types that I definitely could play before (and can in Windows, other linux distros, etc).  Rhythmbox can't play any of my music (mostly .mp3s).  I tried installing VLC, and that plays without a hitch.  Somehow I think my codecs have gotten screwed up.  I'm fairly settled in to this install and don't really want to go through the reinstall again, so I'd like to get this sorted out.  Initially I hadn't made any package changes that really would have affected codecs.  In attempts to troubleshoot the issue I've tried manually installing/uninstalling/repairing various related packages.

On a hunch, I just tried logging in as a different user.  It was able to play the same videos without issue, so I'm pretty sure it's a profile setting.  What folder should I take a look at (or try to rename/delete)?  Some other setting I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this problem, I'll go ahead and post my solution. After discovering it was profile specific, I set off to try to find relevant config settings. The solution for me was to remove/rename the ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0 folder. I did rename a few others, but I'm fairly certain this was the fix.